# Zenity not dealing well with a list with multiple columns

Tags: bash, gtk, fedora, gnome, zenity

I have been trying to code a small installer script for Fedora, but when it reaches my `zenity` list it says `This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.` and the std-output is `255`. My code is as follows:

```sh
zenity --list --text="Choose apps to install!" --checklist --mulitple --hide-column=4 --print-column=4 --seperator=" " \
--column="Install?" --column="Name"  --column="Description" --column="Package Name"\
FALSE "Chromium" "Basically Chrome" "chromium"\
FALSE "GNOME Tweaks" "Change the font and theme" "gnome-tweaks"\
FALSE "Pitivi" "Video editing application like iMovie" "pitivi"\
FALSE "Blender" "A 3D modeling application" "blender"\
FALSE "Steam" "A platform to buy, install, and play games" "steam"
```

I have tried putting the numbers in strings, reordering the options, and nothing has worked. Is it just my Zenity, or is my code bad? Thanks to anyone who can help. :)

Comment: I really don't know, but at first glance these two options seem contradictory: `--hide-column=4 --print-column=4`. Also, you missed some `=` in `--column "Description" --column "Package Name"`.

Comment: @Socowi It is to hide the package names but also print them to the output to make it as friendly as possible; I removed the `--hide-column` and the output did not change.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a typo error: use **--multiple** in place of --mulitple
2. **Don't use** contradictory options --hide-column=4 --print-column=4
3. There is a typo error: use **--separator** in place of --seperator
4. Option --separator=" " is not true against FALSE and **result with mismatched columns**, hence, remove this option also.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The `seperator` was making it crash It needs to be spelled `separator`. Silly me!